# How can I download Ubuntu onto a mac, then use it on a Windows PC?

Tags: system-installation

I found an older question saying to download Unetbootin which I did.  BUT when I get to this part...

> Select the Ubuntu ISO file you downloaded and click the Open button.

HOW does one select the ISO file?

[image: unetbootin]

I clicked the bullet for disk image but the button with three dots that SHOULD let me see the desktop is showing a blank desktop.  Isn't it suppose to show me what's ON my desktop including the file I need it to see?   It's not.
What do I do now?

Comment: If you are on mac, use https://etcher.io/

Comment: Did you click the `...` button to the right?

Comment: Did you download the `.iso` image, too? Otherwise, you can choose to download it automatically selecting the first bullet (named `Distribution`) and choosing directly from the dropdown menu `[== Select Version ==]`.

Comment: Well I've given up on this totally.  NOT going to go on line with this windows piece of junk.  It's just storage for my camera cards at this point.  here, the whole saga of everything that's been tried is on this forum post  https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/need-help-installing-so-very-lost-4175637969/

Comment: Issues with running Mac software (i.e. UNetbootin) are off-topic here. You can ask on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) instead. Otherwise, you could change the question to be more like "UNetbootin is not working. What other options do I have?"

Comment: Also I just skimmed your forum post and noticed you're talking about Elementary OS, which is not an official Ubuntu flavour, so it's not supported here.

Answer (score 1):

use Etcher!

fast and easy software

https://etcher.io